# Training a Bert word embedding model in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, bert-language-model

I have my own corpus of plain text. I want to train a Bert model in TensorFlow, similar to gensim's word2vec to get the embedding vectors for each word.

What I have found is that all the examples are related to any downstream NLP tasks like classification. But, I want to train a Bert model with my custom corpus after which I can get the embedding vectors for a given word.

Any lead will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the required hardware, you can dig into NVIDIA's training scripts for BERT using TensorFlow. The repo is [here](https://github.com/NVIDIA/DeepLearningExamples/tree/master/TensorFlow/LanguageModeling/BERT#setup). From the [medium article](https://medium.com/future-vision/bert-meets-gpus-403d3fbed848):

> BERT-large can be pre-trained in 3.3 days on four DGX-2H nodes (a
>   total of 64 Volta GPUs).

If you don't have an enormous corpus, you will probably have better results fine-tuning an available model. If you would like to do so, you can look into huggingface's [transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/examples.html#roberta-bert-and-masked-language-modeling).